# Helm values.yaml issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have a Helm chart containing the following contents:

```yaml
# parentchart/charts/subchart/templates/test.yaml
chart: {{ .Values }}
```

```yaml
# parentchart/values.yaml
xyz: def
subchart:
  abc:
    param:
  ankit: kansal
```

```yaml
# parentchart/charts/subchart/values.yaml
abc:
     param1:
ankit: kansal
```

But while templating this chart using `values.yaml` and in other case without using `values.yaml`. I am seeing different values of `.Values`.

Scenario 1, without passing `values.yaml`: if I run `helm template fm parentchart` it outputs

```yaml
---
# Source: parentchart/charts/subchart/templates/test.yaml

chart: map[abc:map[param:<nil> param1:<nil>] ankit:kansal global:map[]]
```

Scenario 2, passing the following `values.yaml`:

```yaml
# values.yaml
xyz: def
subchart:
  abc:
    param:
  ankit: kansal
```

`helm template fm parentchart -f values.yaml` outputs:

```yaml
---
# Source: parentchart/charts/subchart/templates/test.yaml

chart: map[abc:map[param1:<nil>] ankit:kansal global:map[]]
```

Not sure why I'm not getting "param" as `nil` in Scenario 2 as I have passed the same in `values.yaml` from outside.

Comment: please try format your code with ``` yaml ``` markdowns.

Comment: Could you also attach your helm version?

Comment: helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.4.0", GitCommit:"3e90cf8bfd2a621fae18c23ddbed947ab5d84bb0", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.10"}

Comment: kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.4", GitCommit:"aab484b039c3fb4bbc68131cd7280f3334dff6d9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-03-10T20:29:13Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.4", GitCommit:"aab484b039c3fb4bbc68131cd7280f3334dff6d9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-03-10T20:21:58Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
mmuser@seliicbl00315:~>

Comment: Could you upgrade K8S version? Could you attach the whole yaml file? Could you attach the steps to reproduce your poroblem?